# Python 3.5.0b3, 3.5.0rc1: How to make tkinter, Idle, and turtle work on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, tkinter, python-idle

I have a problem with Python installation on Win 7 Pro.
Python 3.5a2 installs without any problems and work ok.
Python 3.5rc1 installs without any problems but idle doesn't work.
The some was with 3.5b3.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: To clarify for future readers: this problem was resolved by the Python 3.5.0 final release, so this is not likely to be relevant unless you've deliberately found the prerelease installers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a a bug in recent 3.5.0 Windows installers.

Symptom: Install 3.5.0rc1 (for instance) on Windows machines without VS2015 installed. Run interactive python and enter `import tkinter` or run a program that does so (Idle, Turtle, turtledemo, or your own). Get message

> Your Python may not be configured for Tk.

Fix: In python35 install directory, find subdirectory `/DLLs`. In that find subdirectory `/MicrosoftVC140.CRT` with one file `vcruntime140.dll`.  Move this file up into `/DLLs` (leaving `/MicrosoftVC140.CRT` empty).  Tkinter should now work.

Comment: This solution solved the problem. Everything works ok.  Thank you very much.